# Is the zero vector inside the set $V = \{ x^2 + a \;|\; a\in\Bbb R\}\subset P_2(\Bbb R)\;?$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the zero vector inside the set $V = \{ x^2 + a\;|\;a\in\Bbb R\}\subset P_2(\Bbb R)\;?$

My textbook says that the $0$ vector is not inside of this set and I was wondering why that is.

Does the $x^2$ in this set assume that the coefficient of $x$ is always $1$, and therefore does not contain the zero vector ?

Comment: Do you see any difference between $x^2+a$ and $1\times x^2+a$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I do not see any difference of course.

Comment: The zero vector is $0x^2+0x+0.$ The coefficient of $x^2$ in $x^2+a$ is $1.$

Comment: Alternatively phrased, if we were to talk about $\Bbb R^3$ instead, do you see the difference between $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,0,0]$?  Or more generally between the sets $\{[1,0,a]~:~a\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\{[0,0,a]~:~a\in\Bbb R\}$

Comment: @Angelo The question was for the OP to answer.

Comment: Just in case if the point of confusion is that $x^2+a$ with the right values of $x$ and the right values of $a$ could equal the real number zero (*for example with $x=2$ and $a=-4$*)... that is irrelevant since here we are talking not about "zero" from $\Bbb R$ but rather "*the zero vector from $P_2(\Bbb R)$.*"  In this context we treat the $x$'s special, as indeterminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible basis of your vector space $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\lbrace 1, x, x^2 \rbrace$. Every element $y \in V$ is of the form $y=a \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 1 \cdot x^2$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The system $\lbrace 1, x, x^2 \rbrace$ is in particular free, so $y=0$ would imply that the coefficients in the previous linear combination are all zero (here $y=0 \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$ means the zero of the vector space, not $0 \in \mathbb{R}$), i.e. $a=0$ and $1=0$ (and the latter is not possible).